# Lift-mapper - inserting items to database

Tags: scala, lift, mapper, lift-mapper

I am trying to add item to H2 database. My code is:

```
class Test extends LongKeyedMapper[Test] with IdPK {
  def getSingleton = Test
  object name extends MappedString(this, 100)
}
```

and `Test.create.name("some_name").id(2).save`, but I always get `java.lang.Exception: Do not have permissions to set this field`. What can I do wrong? Connection is of course open and I have permission to data from database.

Answer (score 3):

`IdPK` extends `MappedLongIndex` which is not writable by default, that's why it restricts you from setting the field. Usually you would let the DB generate an PK ID automatically for you via autoincrement field (postgres, mysql), trigger + sequence (oracle), etc. So in most common scenarios you don't need to set this field. To be able to still set it add an override like this on your field:

```
override def writePermission_? = true
```

Comment: Shouldn't this instead be `override def writePermission_? = true` ?

Comment: Thank you @ShafiqueJamal for the correction, indeed to be able to write to this field the value should be 'true', I updated the answer.